# make typedefs incompatible

Tags: c++

Situation:

```
typedef int TypeA;
typedef int TypeB;
```

I need to make TypeA incompatible with TypeB (so any attempt to assign TypeA to TypeB would trigger compile error), while retaining all functionality provided by built-in type (operators).

One way to do it is to wrap each type into separate struct/class (and redefine all operators, etc).

Is there any other, more "elegant", way to do it?

Third party libraries are not allowed. C++0x/C++11x is not supported. (C++ 2003 is supported)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Discriminating between typedefs to same type in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129078/discriminating-between-typedefs-to-same-type-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way is to create a new type (by using for example [BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/boost/strong_typedef.hpp)).

Comment: Ok, now, Boost is Magic; but how does that pass through access to the wrapped type's members and methods?

Comment: @Chowlett Looking at the implementation of BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF, I see that [they re-implemented all operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/boost/operators.hpp).

Comment: I can see that inheriting from `totally_ordered2<...>` provides access to all _comparison_ operators, through `less_than_comparable` and `equality_comparable`. But I can't see how, if I `BOOST_STRING_TYPEDEF(std::string, Foo);`, I can then do `Foo foo = "foo"; foo.length();`

Comment: We may be talking at cross purposes, but that would seem to imply that [this](http://codepad.org/wu2LXEuB) should work; it doesn't, clearly, so what have boost done to make `myFoo.length();` work?

Comment: @Chowlett Actually, you need to access it like in [this example](http://codepad.org/30jnnOmj)

Comment: Ah, and you need to do that with the Boost one too? In which case, I understand.

Comment: @Chowlett Yes, that's how you access the Boost type (except it is `t`, not `foo`)

Answer (score 0):

To trigger compiler errors, you may make both types as classes. In `TypeA`, make a conversion operator and/or constructor that converts to/from `TypeB` - and make these methods **private**.

This way, any conversion from `TypeB` to `TypeA` would call for the conversion function, and compiler would emit error that that method is private! Ensure that you may need to write few conversion operators/constructors from/to you want conversion to happen successfully. I mean, if you want conversion from `float`, you need to write constructor taking `float` and so on for other types.

You may write conversion operators, constructors in either `TypeA` or `TypeB`, and list of allowable conversions in these classes.

Comment: Can I use the resulting type with all operators then, without forwarding them manually?